# Compiling mcrypt fails (gaa: Command not found)

Tags: makefile, centos6, mcrypt

I have to compile PHP with mcrypt, but for some reason i cannot compile mcrypt using the make command. I´m getting the following error:

```
gaa -o gaaout.c -i gaa.h mcrypt.gaa
make[2]: gaa: Command not found
make[2]: *** [gaaout.c] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mcrypt-2.6.7/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mcrypt-2.6.7'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I´m compiling it on Centos 6.6, and the mcrypt version is 2.6.7

Before i compiled i installed the Development Tools packaged via yum.
    `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

Also installed: `mhash (v 0.9.9.9), libmcrypt (v 2.5.8)`

What is the gaa command, and how do i make i available?

Comment: How are you compiling mcrypt? I.e. are you using the --with-mcrypt flag when compiling PHP or some other way?

Comment: I was thinking that i would compile and install mcrypt first and then compile php with a reference to the mcrypt installation, i think i did it like that before? 

Is it enough just to compile php with the --with-mcrypt flag?

I guess i need to install mcrypt for the --with-mcrypt flag to work?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: don't know `gaa` either, but since `src/gaaout.c` exists:

```
touch src/gaaout.c
```

did the trick for me.